# Does the Ubuntu One sync work?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, connection

I have been on this for several hours now, trying to get a simple second folder to sync with my (paid) account.

I cannot tell you how many times I removed all devices, removed stored passwords, killed all processes of u1, logged out and back in online...and still, the tick in the file browser (Synchronize this folder) is loading and loading and loading.

Also, I have logged out, rebooted countless times.

And this is after me somehow managing to get the u1 preferences to finally "connect" again.

I have also checked the status of your services, and none are close to what I am experiencing.
And I have checked the suggested related questions above!

So please, just confirm whether it is a problem on my side, or a problem on your side.

EDIT:

In the mean time, here is what has changed, on top of what is mentioned just above.

• My files went from 0MB to 71.9MB, and is still rising.
• My first folder of 400.2MB is being filled with the data as I write this. The second folder has the folder sub-structure in place.
• Both folders now show in the File Browser that it will be synchronized.

I believe that right now, it is all back to normal and working fine, and I guess that's what a good night's sleep can do ;). And we're now only back to the point where synchronizing is slow, but will pick up with the release of Natty (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync).

But to get to the questions:

1. My about says I use 11.04, Natty Narwhal, but I am quite sure the last distribution I installed was 10.10.
2. Folder A is 400.2MB, and Folder B is 29.5MB
3. I am on a DSL line, behind a regular fritz.box setting.
4. No proxy servers in use, and I did not install any particular firewall features.
5. No physical firewall, just the router (on which I have a TV signal as well), and 2 switches to get to this floor.
6. Status: inactive
   The ubuntuone-indicator runs the same window as when I click on my name on the top-right corner and select Ubuntu one, or in the Control Center choose Ubuntu one. It wasn't supposed to go further than this was it?

Comment: If that wasn't clear in my post, the u1 preferences / devices screen shows my computer alright, the connect button is no longer clickable, the restart button is, and so is the remove button. And at the top of the window, it says Disconnected, and 0%. Contacts have worked very fine with the iPhone. And my first folder is there, but only the folder structure, no content.

Comment: On our side? This is a community site; it has not owned or run by Canonical.

Comment: @frabjous The Ubuntu One team takes questions here, see: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=664

Comment: I'd love to throw money at Canonical for a solid UbuntuOne implementation, but in my very limited experience it is perhaps the least robust of their efforts.

Comment: Btw, in 17 hours (since my first post), it has now uploaded about 180MB. I hope this will not be an indicator of sync speeds in the future...

Comment: Since my initial post, I have managed to sync a total of 1.8GB (in 48hours?). This is much better than the initial less than 180MB in 17hours, but with another 36 or so GB I was hoping to sync, it'll take me approximately 40 days to be up to speed...Yay. I have also now posted a support request through their (other) official site, and will see what they reply, and of course keep you posted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a big fan or user of Ubuntu One, but I'll try to help.  You'll probably need to outline some additional details :

1. Version of Ubuntu you're running.
2. Size of folder you're trying to sync.
3. How are you connected to the internet?  Is this is a home broadband service, or a corporate setting?
4. Are you using a proxy server to connect to the internet?
5. Are you using a firewall, hardware or otherwise?  Perhaps one built in to your broadband router (what make is your broadband router)?
6. Please post the results of running `sudo ufw status` in a terminal.

You might also benefit from running the (unofficial, I think) gnome-panel indicator applet for Ubuntu One.  Run this to install it :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator
```

Then run it with ALT-F2 and `ubuntuone-indicator`.  I think it's in System/Preferences too.
This applet gives you quick access to see what the last file synced was and what Ubuntu One's current status is.

And it sounds like you've already done this, but best check the official FAQ here :
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ#Files

Finally, if you followed Jorge's link to the Ubuntu One blog, you'll see that there's an official support program in place.  Raise a ticket here :
https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/

Comment: Hello all and thank you for the many replies!

First off, apologies to frabjous. I assumed that as I had clicked on the support option on the u1 preferences screen, that I'd end up in a place where Ubuntu somehow was connected ;)

Jorge ;)

msw, I have still high hopes to prove both our fears wrong, as over night, the screen now shows "Synchronization in progress...", and it is now on 0.3% usage ;)

And then Scaine, thank you so much for taking the time for helping me!!

Comment: My files went from 0MB to 71.9MB, and is still rising.
• My first folder of 400.2MB is being filled with the data as I write this. The second folder has the folder sub-structure in place.
• Both folders now show in the File Browser that it will be synchronized.

I believe that right now, it is all back to normal and working fine, and I guess that's what a good night's sleep can do ;). And we're now only back to the point where synchronizing is slow, but will pick up with the release of Natty (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync).

Comment: But to get to the questions:
1. My about says I use 11.04, Natty Narwhal, but I am quite sure the last distribution I installed was 10.10.
2. Folder A is 400.2MB, and Folder B is 29.5MB
3. I am on a DSL line, behind a regular fritz.box setting.
4. No proxy servers in use, and I did not install any particular firewall features.
5. No physical firewall, just the router (on which I have a TV signal as well), and 2 switches to get to this floor.
6. Status: inactive

Comment: The ubuntuone-indicator runs the same window as when I click on my name on the top-right corner and select Ubuntu one, or in the Control Center choose Ubuntu one. It wasn't supposed to go further than this was it? [[ Apologies for my truncated message, I felt it would be rude to just cut it down to 500 chars.. and many thanks again for your help!!]]

Comment: @bisi Put all the information in your last two comments in your original question (click the edit button). That way all your information is at the top and not buried in comments, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I have been trying to sync my documents folder of 1.4GB, it still hasn't worked and it has been syncing for a month. The top level syncs, files and folders in the Document folders, but contents of sub-folders just hang.

I have tried using the backup facility in 11.10, to backup to Ubuntu One.... I upgraded my HDD space in Ubuntu One. It has been going now for 24hours and only backed up what looks like a couple of percent.

The odd thing is I can sync to drop box within hours, rather than months.

This is bad, and has been an issue since Ubuntu One's release. I have reported this problem and there were promises in later releases this would be fixed, but it hasn't.

Canonical cannot help either...

So my advice is to use dropbox or another service, until it is sorted, but as Ubuntu does not seem to see this as an issue, I think a fix will be a long time in coming.

Yes my internet speeds are fine, etc... :-)

Thanks